# Is it possible to specify multiple email addresses to receive bounce messages?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, email-bounces

We're using [JavaMail API](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/) to send emails from our application.  To handle bounce back messages ([Non delivery report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report)),
we're redirecting bounce backs to a different email address using the following code:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.from", "bounce@example.net");
```

In our case, we want bounce backs to be redirected to multiple email addresses.  In fact, we even tried few other options like providing a list of addresses separated by commas, etc., but none of them are working.

My question here is, is it possible to redirect bounce backs to **multiple email addresses**? I'm not able to find the right answer/solution even after googling.

Any alternative/workaround solution are also appreciated.

Comment: Bounce to one email address, which automatically forwards everything it received to several other email addresses.

Comment: what about properties.put("mail.smtp.from", "bounce@example.net;bounce2@example.net"); ?

Comment: @fredley: How does `automatically forwards everything ...` works?

Comment: @nidhin: I tried that option (semicolon) as well.  It's *not* working.

Comment: @Gnanam Most mailboxes have settings for forwarding

Comment: @fredley: Thanks for the clarification and suggesting a workaround. So, it is not possible to specify multiple email addresses for bounce backs programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since by definition/RFC the SMTP protocol allows only one address in "MAIL FROM:" Stage (which is the bounce address), the only way of having bounces sent to multiple recipients would be a forwarder from a single bounce address to multiple target adresses.

however, all bounces by would come from the null sender, so you wouln't get any notification if that forwarding fails for any reaseon, it would create a "double-bounce", and the messages would be deleted.

Therefore, I recommend storing the bounces in an imap folder and give all required people or applications access to that (eg. polling the bounces instead of forwarding), if that is feasible in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.  Can you help/point me exactly in [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) spec, where it `allows only one address in "MAIL FROM:" Stage`?  Also, when you say `all bounces by would come from the null sender`, I couldn't understand about null sender.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-3.3

   `There are three steps to SMTP mail transactions.  The transaction
   starts with a MAIL command that gives the sender identification. [...] A series of one or more RCPT
   commands follows, [...]`
 => only one MAIL command, but one or more RCPT TO

**null sender**: non-delivery report messages have an empty enelope sender address ("<>") to prevent failed delivery of the NDR to create a new bounce (bounces going back and forth). more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message#Terminology

Comment: Thanks again. Though my next question is off topic, I'm just wondering how this works in real-time.  Assuming I've application access (again using JavaMail) to IMAP folders, how do I differentiate between new email and emails that are already been processed/read?  What is the recommended polling frequency?  Any articles/links related to this are really appreciated.

Comment: in IMAP, read messages get a "\Seen" flag. I don't know tje java mail api but there are probably methods to query unseen messages only.

Comment: OK, I'll check with JavaMail API.  But is the `seen` flag available with POP3 also?

Comment: nope, POP3 doesn't have seen flags. the read/unread thing is usually handled by the client (they keep a list of seen messages locally)

Comment: just had an idea: if you don't want to use a commonn imap box for all bounce handlers, you could use a forwarder to multiple addresses, but you'd have to configure it to replace the null sender with a mailbox in your domain. in that case, if the forwarding fails, it wouldn't produce a double bounce but send the error message to that configured address. Eg. : bounce@example.net forwards to bouncehandler1@example.net, bouncehandler2@example.net but with a sender address of bounce-errors@example.net.  Not sure if all mailservers support configuring forwarders that way though.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Email allows bounce off. But unfortunately it takes single String and does not allow Collection of InternetAddress. 
`HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setBounceAddress("bounceoff-emailad@abc.com");`
Hope this helps